# I can't get MovieClip(parent).play():void; to function correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, movieclip

I've been trying to make a parent of my movieclip to run, both via button and frame function. Neither were working. I'd got a warning everytime. This is a simple code I suppose. I never work with as3. But I need this to get done.

Here is what I did. As far as I read, it should be working, it just 1 child really. I use with and without 'this.' function. But nothing's working.

```
closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, close);

function close(e:MouseEvent):void{
   MovieClip(this.parent).play():void;
}
```

I expect the parent timeline would `play()` or `gotoandplay()` as it should in as2. But I got warning of;

```
Symbol 'mcSetting_001_bubble', Layer 'ac_', Frame 1, Line 4, Column 33  1078: Label must be a simple identifier.
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include `:void` when calling a function, only when defining one. 
Try changing the code to:

```
closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, close);

function close(e:MouseEvent):void{
   MovieClip(this.parent).play();
}
```

**(1)** The compiler picked up the `:` and thought you were trying to create a label in the code, hence that particular error message.

**(2)** Don't use `close` as a function name since that's already a compiler **keyword** in AS3 language. Try renaming it to `_close` or something else. This way it wont clash with AS3's own built-in `close`.

Comment: Hi @Not so Veteran, i have to reply you in answer section. many thanks for replying.

Comment: Thank you so much @VC.One. That is very helpful!! You are awesome. Both of you. Now the warning has gone, why it won't play parent movieclip? If I may ask.

Comment: @KAMALMASRUN It's not obvious what the `this` in your `MovieClip(this.parent)` is talking to. Might be easier to just give an _instance_ name to the MC you want to play (like you did with instance name `closeBtn`) and then use code like `myMCname.play();`.

Comment: PS: Don't forget to mark the posted Answer as solution by clicking the big grey `✔` icon next to the Answer. That's how you show thanks to volunteers.

Comment: Hi @VC.One, i did put an instance name to my mc. It does not working anyway. However, I tried `MovieClip(parent.parent)`, surprisingly it worked. I don't know how or why it worked with 2 `parent` like that, because it just 1 level of mc. Anyway, you guys are helpful nonetheless. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. i did remove `:void`. but i got warning instead, everytime. here's the warning.

```
Symbol 'mcSetting_001_bubble', Layer 'ac_', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 10  1023: Incompatible override.
Symbol 'mcSetting_001_bubble', Layer 'ac_', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 10  1021: Duplicate function definition.
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2019\Common\Configuration\Camera\Flash\privatePkg\___LayerProp___.as, Line 1, Column 1  5000: The class 'privatePkg.___LayerProp___' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
```

i can't reply in the comment. it's too long, i'm sorry.

btw, `column 10` is at function `close` name.